# Jquery If but And Else Statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, window-resize

I have this code and blurb-top p gets hidden when I click on ul. But when the window is resized, the ul click function doesn't work. So how would I also incorporate the 'ul' addClass hidden in the window resize function too? I'm looking to keep everything as is, since it's working fine. Only update it to say, if window is resized, remove class hidden, else addClass BUT if window is resized AND 'ul' is clicked, addClass hidden? Can anyone help me with this, please? Thank YOU!

**JS:**

```
$('ul').click(function () {
    $('blurb-top p').addClass('hidden');
});

window.onresize = function () {
    if ($(".project_thumb").css("margin-bottom") === "1px") {
        $('.blurb-top p').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $('.blurb-top p').addClass('hidden');
    }
};       


EDITED CODE
```

Something like this?

```
window.onresize = function () {
    if ($(".project_thumb").css("margin-bottom") === "1px") {
        $('.blurb-top p').removeClass('hidden');
    } else if

    ($(".project_thumb").css("margin-bottom") === "1px");
    $('ul').click(function () {
        $('.blurb-top p').addClass('hidden');

    }
    else 
    $('#Grid > .blurb-top p').addClass('hidden');

   ; };
```

Comment: "BUT if window is resized AND 'ul' is clicked" do you mean "if the 'blurb-top p' has the class hidden?"

Comment: If the window is resized, and project thumb has css margin bottom 1px, blurb-top p won't have the class hidden. UNLESS, 'ul' is clicked. Does that make sense?

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. Do you mean at the point when the window is resized, if the ul has been clicked at some time previously, add the class?

Comment: On window resize-with the condition that .project_thumb has a margin-bottom of 1px- then removeClass hidden. If window is resized BUT 'ul' is clicked, then addClass hidden. And for everything else, addClass hidden too.